# What are the methods available to get the CPU usage in Linux Command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

We know that `top` is a command to get the CPU usage in Linux and other ways include 
`cat /proc/stat` which is used by top.

What are other methods to get the CPU usage in the Linux command line?

**Use case scenario:**  The output of this command will be used by a script to log the CPU usage continuously. `top` and `/proc/stat` give detailed usage which is difficult to log. Is there an easier way to get the CPU info?

Comment: what is wrong with the ones you quote?

Comment: @pataluc It give more detailed information. I need a overall CPU usage say CPU used : 91%  Mem Used:78% Mem Free:22% something like this..

Comment: see Nathan's answer... you can `sed` the result if you only want the value.

Comment: Voting to close as "not constructive".  From http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask: "*To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: 'I use ______ for ______, what do you use?'*"

Comment: @DragonLord actually, there are quite limited ways of doing this and the two answers here are in fact useful. Mine points out a very common misconception  about `top` and the other gives a very useful command. It is not a _I use X, how 'bout you?_ question, but a _How do I do X_ question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me so I came up with this: https://mohammadg.com/linux/how-to-get-overall-cpu-utilization-from-the-bash-command-line/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have said, the best way is probably `top`. It needs a little tweaking and a little parsing but you can get it to give you the current CPU use as a percentage.

`top` splits CPU usage between user, system processes and `nice` processes, we want the sum of the three. So, we can run `top` in `b`atch mode which allows us to parse its output. However, as explained [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619), the 1st iteration of `top -b` returns the percentages since boot, we therefore need at least two iterations (`-n 2`) to get the current percentage. To speed things up, you can set the `d`elay between iterations to `0.01`. Finally, you `grep` the line containing the CPU percentages and then use `gawk` to sum user, system and nice processes:

```
    top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^%Cpu' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'
        -----  ------   -----------    ---------   ----------------------
          |      |           |             |             |------> add the values
          |      |           |             |--> keep only the 2nd iteration
          |      |           |----------------> keep only the CPU use lines
          |      |----------------------------> set the delay between runs
          |-----------------------------------> run twice in batch mode
```

I thought you could also get this information through `ps -o pcpu ax` by adding the %use of each running process. Unfortunately, as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58541/22222), `ps` "returns the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process" which is not what you need.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, your version of `top` is different to mine and you should use this instead:

```
top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^Cpu.s.' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'
```

And, to avoid issues with localization, set the locale to C:

```
LC_ALL=C top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^Cpu.s.' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because what you said is correct. This one seems to be a valid method.

Comment: @NathanC I thought your answer was correct too, it was what I would have answered. Then I tested it and was surprised :).

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your detailed answer... I couldn't able to get the output for the above command. Is there any syntactical modification required..

Comment: @fasil no, it should work. What is the problem? Any error messages?

Comment: @terdon  I don't get any output for the complete command.. with #top -bn 2 -d 0.01 I get the full result but on adding grep '^%Cpu' I don't see any output  just the prompts returns no error...

Comment: @fasil huh, that should just select the line with the CPU percentage. Perhaps you have a slightly different version of `top`. Try `grep '^.Cpu'` and if that doesn't work, please post the output of `top -bn 1 | head` so I can see what to grep for.

Comment: @terdon  top - 11:50:11 up  1:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.10, 0.18
Tasks: 205 total,   1 running, 204 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.4%sy,  0.3%ni, 97.2%id,  1.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3508264k total,  3383992k used,   124272k free,  1522968k buffers
Swap:  6144820k total,        0k used,  6144820k free,   722444k cached

Comment: @fasil OK, you seem to be using an older version of `top`, see updated answer.

Comment: @terdon : It work fine.. thanks for your modifications...

Comment: You might need to force running top with C locales, as the format of the `-d` parameter depends on it, as well as the format of it's output (awk doesn't understand comma as a decimal delimiter, for example): `LC_ALL=C top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^%Cpu' | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print $2+$4+$6}'`

Answer (score 10):

`sar` is the definitive way to do it.  So for instance  `sar -u` will output something like this:

```
08:30:01 AM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait     %idle
08:40:01 AM       all      6.94      0.00      1.77      4.92     86.36
08:50:01 AM       all      5.73      0.00      2.31     12.72     79.24
09:00:01 AM       all      5.95      0.00      2.58     18.36     73.11
09:10:01 AM       all      6.88      0.00      2.22     17.44     73.45
09:20:01 AM       all      8.61      0.00      2.68     27.93     60.78
```

You don't say which Linux you use but for CentOS/RedHat you need to install the `sysstat` package, and I think it's the same on Debian/Ubuntu.

You can also use sar to gather statistics *ad hoc*:

```
sar -o /tmp/sar.out 60 600
```

Will gather stats every 60 seconds 600 times, so 600 minutes.

Comment: You should probably phrase it different. The line you posted will measure every 60 seconds, 600 times. The way I read your post was that the 600 is a duration, so if I put 30 600, it would take every 30 seconds for 600 minutes, however it would actually take one every 30 seconds 600 times.