# How can I monitor CPU frequency on Linux servers?

Tags: linux, power-management, cpu-speed

At low CPU frequency, latencies can be higher or we may come to some wrong conclusions related to server capacity.

Knowing the CPU frequency is important for high performance scenarios.

In case of Linux-controlled P-States we can find the current scaling governors and CPU frequency, but hardware vendors like HP have HP Dynamic Power Saving Model. Dell has Active Power Controller and Intel provides Intel Turbo Boost, due to which CPU frequency can change and hence the performance results can vary.

Is there any command line tool or other method in Linux to monitor CPU frequency of cores?

Answers to the above suggested question does not answer this question.

Comment: @BlueBerry - vignesh4303. Please dont confuse cpu frequency issues with CPU usage. They are quite different and this question has no relation with the question you have pointed out.

Comment: The question http://superuser.com/questions/609949/what-are-the-methods-available-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-linux-command-line is not related to my question. How can I get moderator help to remove it from the top of this question?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. This just informs you that it might be a duplicate, but it's not closed yet. You could edit your question and specifically mention why the other question doesn't answer yours, though.

Answer (score 1):

Queried my debian (wheezy) box:

```
> cpufreqd - fully configurable daemon for dynamic frequency and voltage scaling
> cpufrequtils - utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
> libcpufreq-dev - development files to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
> libcpufreq0 - shared library to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
```

Comment: The infrastructure for controlling the CPU's current P-state in Linux is known as CPUFREQ. When the cpu frequency changes are not done by the Linux kernel these are not helpful.