# Which tools can log system resources usages in Windows/Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, logging, resource-monitor

I need a tool can log at least a few things like this:

- CPU load: (min/max/average)
- RAM load: (min/max/average)
- Storage size: (max/is used)
- Storage/folder growth size.

AFAIK, Linux shell can help me a bit. But on Windows, I have no idea.

I don't mind if we need to use programming language. I can use Qt (Preferred) and C#.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is a new site, right? I'm looking for a reliable tool, but using shell script, even coding is acceptable. So I think it ain't necessary to move the question to softwarerecs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **Sysstat** in Linux? It is a package of system monitoring tools. One that will fit you will be called **sat**.

You can downloaded it from [here](http://www.log-expert.de/)

Otherwise, you can use your package manager to install. Use one of the command depends on your Linux distribution.

```
sudo yum install sysstat

or 

sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

For Windows, I can't point out one tool that will help you. But, you can try

[LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/)

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Finally, check this one called [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/processlasso/)

All the best

Comment: Do you have any recommendations about Windows?

Comment: Check above, I added some tools for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [What are the methods available to get the CPU usage in Linux Command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/609949/what-are-the-methods-available-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-linux-command-line/610036#610036) in which I explain how to use `sar` to get cpu usage etc.  In order to get `sar` you will need the package `sysstat` as @passionate_tester mentions above.

For more general monitoring you could use a tool like [Xymon](http://xymon.sourceforge.net/) which will track disk space usage, CPU load, system uptime, etc.  It can be used to monitor a wide range of operating systems, including Windows of course.  However it won't give quite the same detail found in `sar`.  On the other hand you can customise Xymon to use `sar`.