# Is there a linux command for current CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, process

On a linux system, is there a command that will give you the current CPU usage?

I know you can visually inspect using top or htop, so the data exists somewhere.

I'd like a command to say "at this current moment, 65% of processing power is being used".

Does such a command exist?

Comment: Check out terdon's answer http://superuser.com/questions/609949/what-are-the-methods-available-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-linux-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
~# uptime
 23:10:00 up 26 days, 11:41,  1 user,  load average: 0.39, 0.24, 0.25
```

Man uptime:

uptime  gives a one line display of the following information.  The current time, how long the system has been running, how many users are currently logged on, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

Comment: Load average is not the same thing as CPU average

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this code:

```
top -BN 2 -d 1:00 | grep '^% Cpu' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $ 2 + $ 4 + $ 6}'
```

I found very useful information on this topic:

[User terdon on supersuser.com detailed this simple code](https://superuser.com/questions/609949/what-are-the-methods-available-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-linux-command-line)

i only edited the interval "-d 1:00" between top reads.

Comment: Answer by terdon works well already, your changes are unwarranted and break the command. I'm downvoting this.

Comment: For me works better with a bigger interval like i posted.